# How to deploy an kops cluster in aws using cloudflare instead Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, kops

I'm wondering if you could tell me how can I  deploy an AWS KOPS cluster using Cloudflare instead Route 53 using a yaml file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean for external-dns or for the k8s API?

Comment: If you can help me with both will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

kOps do not support using cloudflare for the API.
For external-dns, see https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/cloudflare.md